# Resizing bootstrap cards to match them

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the card bootstrap parameters, but my differents card-img-top resizes differently. I'm searching for css in order to make them even but trying to maintain the same quality or similar.

[image: The idea is to match the cards in size w/o losing too much quality]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```css
.card-img-top {
  height: 15vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: changed the code a little bit but it worked!, ty

Comment: Youre Welcome
Send the snippet of the full result